# Sun Grid Engine DRMAA java memory leak

Tags: java, sungridengine, drmaa

I am using sun grid engine and java DRMAA library to schedule jobs on to the cluster from inside a web application. Everything works well as far as jobs are concerned. But the application memory usuage is growing rapidly as the time goes and when i start to submit multiple jobs to the cluster. Have anyone noticed the same behaviour. I could use some experts help on this.